# Can I remove the weblinks component if I upgrade from Joomla 3.3 to 3.4?

Tags: component, upgrade, weblinks, joomla-3.4

I'm currently on Joomla 2.5. I've been hanging out for Joomla 3.4 to be released before migrating, but I can't wait any longer.

Will I be able to remove the weblinks component once I upgrade from Joomla 3.3 to 3.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weblinks component is not a locked extension and can be uninstalled anyway, even in your current J2.5 site.

**Update:**

Note though, that despite the component is allowed to be uninstalled, doing so can possibly give you minor issues when updating/upgrading Joomla, mostly within the database because of the absence of the relative tables.

Comment: True true. That's the last time I try to answer a question this early in the morning. **Grabs another coffee**

Comment: Okay it's really true, we can uninstall weblinks, but I didn't mention that doing so there is a possibility of creating minor issues when updating/upgrading, which however can be easily fixed. Have a nice day Lodder!

Comment: @FFrewin Thanks. I'll probably wait till J3.4 to uninstall it. Hopefully that will bypass the minor issues that you mentioned.

Comment: Not sure if J2.5 allows it or not, but in J3.x you can disable a component in the component manager - maybe this is a clearner way to avoid update/upgrade issues.